# UploadiFive uploading speed

Tags: jquery, html, file-upload, uploadify

I'm using UploadiFive (HTML5 version, not a Flash) as my upload engine. It working great, but there is any way to show the uploading speed? Seems Uploadify (Flash version) have this feature. Thanks in advance!

Comment: would this be of any help? http://www.uploadify.com/forum/#/discussion/5001/can-i-display-both-upload-speed-and-percentage/p1 or maybe this http://www.uploadify.com/forum/#/discussion/248/how-to-set-displaydata-value/p1

Comment: Unfortunately, not. This is only applicable for Uploadify (Flash version), but not for UploadiFive (HTML5 version). I need this feature exactly for UploadiFive.